# Запуск JQuery скрипта по обновлению части страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть скрипт который необходимо запускать после любого обновления страницы, а точнее секции на этой странице.
Например у меня есть секция заполнения данных, после нажатия на кнопку отправить у меня происходит проверка введенных данных а обновление секции с полями для ввода, и после этого обновления должен запустится скрипт
Скрипт предназначен для установки фокуса в первое поле ввода с ошибкой

```
$('[style *= "none"]').each(function(indx){
    var klacc = $(this).attr("class");
    if (klacc == "iconErrorDiv dynamic-icon-error-div")
    {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
  var errdiv = $('div.iconErrorDiv').first();
  $(errdiv).siblings('input, select').focus();
  var el = $(errdiv).siblings('input, select, textarea').attr("id");
  var scrollTo = document.getElementByID(el);
  scrollTo.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: А почему бы не запустить эту функцию при клике на отправку... до отправки всё проверить и не отправлять, если там окажется ошибка...

Comment: Я пробовал выполнять скрипт при клике на кнопку отправки. После отправки происходит обновление секции и собственно сам крипт не выполняется, переход на поле не происходит, хотя после обновлния если я нажимаю на кнопку на которой нет ни какого функционала кроме этого скрипта все работает

Comment: вот заканчивается обновление секции с полями и следом запускайте скрипт. Мониторить изменения в доме мне кажется не очень производительно получится.

Comment: был бы круто если не одно но, у меня кнопок шт 50 а то ибольше по всей площадке,вот я и хотел бы просто прикрутить его на загрузку страницы, но проблема в том что на саму закгрузку он реагирует, но после обновления (хоть целиком страницы, хоть ее части) скрипт не выполняется

Comment: Куча житейских ошибок, таких как `getElementByID` => `getElementById`. Пробуйте `$(document).ready(function() {$('div.iconErrorDiv').get(0).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});});` поставить в начало скрипта..

Comment: Рустам большое вам спасибо, Ваш совет уменьшил мой код и сделал его более наглядным, да и внешне процесс прокрутки стал приятно выглядеть, но все равно при попытке запуска его после обновления страницы ни каких успехов нет

Comment: $(document).ready и $(window).load работают только 1 раз при загрузке страницы, ajax загрузки туда не входят. Может быть это поможет https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: Skywave спасибо большое, все заработало, + у меня у самого была ошибка которую я не заметил - указал не все типы полей в siblind вот он и не мог установить фокус и прокрутить так как в первом результате не было нужного поля